# How to RESTART a specific command if it fails in Windows Batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

In a BAT file I start 2 separate processes like so:
As you can see the only difference is the CPU affinity.

```
start /realtime /affinity FFFF C:\Users\telis\Documents\CHIA\madmax\plotter\chia_plot.exe

start /realtime /affinity FFFF0000 C:\Users\telis\Documents\CHIA\madmax\plotter\chia_plot.exe
```

Sometimes, randomly, one of the 2 processes fails with:
*Problem Event Name:    BEX64*

It is essential that the process is restarted immediately when a failure like this happens. So I am faced with this problem.

> Can I monitor within the BAT file the 2 processes and if one fails to
> restart it? The monitoring process must be able to distinguish which
> of the 2 processes has failed, so that the correct affinity is used to
> restart it.

If you have a solution involving powershell please visit [How to RESTART a specific command if it fails in Windows Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368101/how-to-restart-a-specific-command-if-it-fails-in-windows-powershell)

Thanks

Comment: As you have tagged 'powershell' are you open to having a powershell-based solution?  If not please remove the tag.

Comment: Sure... I would prefer to do it all in powershell actually

Comment: I do not want to restrict people... maybe someone knows a way in batch and someone else in powershell. I should therefore leave this question as is now... and open a separate question specifically for powershell where I will post the same thing with PS commands. Do you agree?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have 32 processors with which to work? By using `-PassThru`, the process object can be used to monitor if the process is still alive.

```
$Process1 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Users\telis\Documents\CHIA\madmax\plotter\chia_plot.exe' -PassThru
$Process1.ProcessorAffinity = 0xF
$Process1.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'
$Process2 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Users\telis\Documents\CHIA\madmax\plotter\chia_plot.exe' -PassThru
$Process2.ProcessorAffinity = 0xF0
$Process2.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'
```

Comment: Thanks lit, I modified slightly your code to repost my question specifically for powershell here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68368101/how-to-restart-a-specific-command-if-it-fails-in-windows-powershell
please follow up if you have any ideas