# How to RESTART a specific command if it fails in Windows Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

In a ps1 file I start 2 separate processes like so:
As you can see the only difference is the CPU affinity.

```
$Process1 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe' -PassThru
$Process1.ProcessorAffinity = 65535
$Process1.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'

$Process2 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe' -PassThru
$Process2.ProcessorAffinity = 4294901760
$Process2.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'
```

Sometimes, randomly, one of the 2 processes fails with:
*Problem Event Name:    BEX64*

It is essential that the process is restarted immediately when a failure like this happens. So I am faced with this problem.

> Can I monitor within the PS1 file the 2 processes and if one fails to
> restart it? The monitoring process must be able to distinguish which
> of the 2 processes has failed, so that the correct affinity is used to
> restart it.

If you have a solution involving windows batch script please visit [How to RESTART a specific command if it fails in Windows Batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367315/how-to-restart-a-specific-command-if-it-fails-in-windows-batch-file)

Thanks

Comment: `Process.ProcessorAffinity` is a bitmask representing the CPUs, so using decimal for it makes zero sense. Use `$Process1.ProcessorAffinity = 0xFFFF` instead of 65535

Comment: actually powershell has asked me to use IntPtr and accepts these values without issue. I am using them because it would not accept 0x00000000FFFF0000

Comment: Who said that 0x00000000FFFF0000 isn't accepted? Unless your CPU has fewer than 32 CPUs. 65535 = 0xFFFF, not 0x00000000FFFF0000. To powershell both decimal and hex literals represent the same value but to human readers the decimal value doesn't make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Process1 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe' -PassThru
$Process1.ProcessorAffinity = 1
$Process1.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'
Write-Host Process ID $process1.Id started with CPU affinity $Process1.ProcessorAffinity

$Process2 = Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe' -PassThru
$Process2.ProcessorAffinity = 2
$Process2.PriorityClass = 'RealTime'
Write-Host Process ID $process2.Id started with CPU affinity $Process2.ProcessorAffinity

while($true){
    foreach($process in $Process1,$Process2){
        if($process.hasexited){

            Write-Host "Process ID $($process.id) has exited, restarting."
            $priority = $process.PriorityClass
            $affinity = $process.ProcessorAffinity
            if($newprocess = $process.Start()){
                Write-Host Successfully restarted process ID $process.Id with CPU affinity $process.ProcessorAffinity
                $process.PriorityClass = $priority
                $process.ProcessorAffinity = $affinity
                Write-Host Priority Class set back to $process.PriorityClass
                Write-Host Process affinity set back to $process.ProcessorAffinity
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
}
```

Comment: Good answer. only problem is that when you restart the process, the affinity and priority are not retained. correct?

Comment: The affinity seemed to be the same in my tests but they were very basic/quick.

Comment: @conanDrum  It seems you are correct about the PriorityClass, I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I get this:Process ID 9744 started with CPU affinity 65535
Process ID 19312 started with CPU affinity 4294901760
Process ID 19312 has exited, restarting.
Successfully restarted as process ID 16120 with CPU affinity 4294967295
Process ID 16120 has exited, restarting.
Successfully restarted as process ID 20084 with CPU affinity 4294967295

Comment: Affinity is always 4294967295